# Mean density of the Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, density

Cavendish gives a unitless number, 5.51, as the mean densitiy of the earth (5.51 times the density of water. So Cavendish takes density of water as unit.) Today we state earth's density as 5515 kg/m^3. How do we arrive at 5515 kg/m^3 from the unitless number 5.51?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The relative density of the Earth as calculated by Cavendish is $5.51$ i.e the mean density of the Earth is 5.51 times the density of water at $4^\circ C$.

The density of water in SI units is $1000$ kg m$^{-3}$. This implies that the mean density of the Earth, according to Cavendish would be $5.51 \times 1000$ kg m$^{-3} = 5510$ kg m$^{-3}$.